# How can I get table_name , report_name and universe_name from SDK?

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I want to get table_name , report_name and universe_name from SDK,

It it possible with Java SDK?

I can get query like this:

```
IInfoObjects infoObjectsUniverse2; 
IInfoStore iStore2;
 

IEnterpriseSession es2=null;
try {
    es2 = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr().logon( user, password, CMSName, cmsAuthType);

//session.setAttribute( "enterpriseSession", es );
iStore2 = (IInfoStore)es2.getService("", "InfoStore");
 

IInfoObjects getuniv;
String queryUniverse = "SELECT  * FROM ci_appobjects WHERE SI_Kind='DSL.MetaDataFile' and SI_SPECIFIC_KIND = 'DSL.Universe'";
getuniv = iStore2.query(queryUniverse);
```

Comment: Which version of SAP Business Objects are you using ? Can you also clarify your needs : what did you mean by table_name and report_name ?

Comment: I use bo 4,1 , I need  which table belongs which universe and report

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the WI report's name (`SI_NAME`) and its associated universes (`SI_UNIVERSE`,`SI_DSL_UNIVERSE`) from the repository:

```
SELECT si_id, si_name, si_universe, si_dsl_universe FROM ci_infoobjects WHERE si_kind='Webi' and si_instance=0
```

Both the `SI_UNIVERSE` and `SI_DSL_UNIVERSE` properties are collections of IDs that you'll need to serialize and include in a second query to get the details about the universes:

```
SELECT * FROM ci_appobjects WHERE si_id IN ([serialized list of IDs])
```

If you just want a list of the UNV or UNX universes, use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ci_appobjects WHERE si_kind IN ('Universe','DSL.Universe')
```

You'll need to use one of the [Universe SDKs](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-38810) to access the universe's collection of tables and such.

You could also try the RESTful Raylight SDK, but good luck finding the documentation--all the links that I've seen are orphans.